# How to fix battlefield 4 directx errors?

Tags: directx, error-reporting

I get this error:

DirectX function “GetDeviceRemovedReason” failed with DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG(“The application’s device failed due to badly formed commands sent by the application. This is an design-time issue that should be investigated and fixed.”).

Any ideas?

Comment: This message means the game's use of the graphics card hung the video hardware and the driver timed out. This is definitely an issue to take to the game's publisher.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few fixes to solve this:

Fix #1: Install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
Fix #2: Run a clean boot on your PC or Mac
Fix #3: Downclock you graphics card

More informations you can find here: http://theitbros.com/battlefield-4-directx-error/

Comment: The idea that installing the VS 2012 CRT REDIST fixes this issue is a red-herring. It can't possibly fix this issue, so reports of it doing anything at all must be conflated with other attempted resolutions.